Drools 9 documentation not available
Although maven repository shows latest drools version as 9 but drools documentation shows 8 as latest version. Any reason behind this mismatch?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core/9.44.0.Final
https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/drools/introduction/index.html

Could it just be an error of uploading artifacts to Maven Central?
There is only a sudden "Drools 9.44.x" archive with nothing preceding it in the "9 major" release, and its date is exactly the one of "Drools 8.44.0 Final": Sep 06, 2023

